# Puppet forge API does not return expected JSON

Tags: puppet

I am trying to access the Puppet Forge API to find the latest version of modules to compare the versions against what's in our current Puppetfile.

As a complete newbie to accessing APIs, however, there is a gap between what I know and what the Forge documentation assumes I know, so I am getting nowhere.

The documentation at https://forgeapi.puppet.com tells me:

> The API is accessed over HTTPS via the forgeapi.puppetlabs.com domain.
>   All data is returned in JSON format.

However, I cannot find any JSON formatted data.

I have a simple Python script that I am using to connect to the server:

```
import requests
r=requests.get("https://forgeapi.puppet.com")
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
```

The content-type is `text/html;charset=utf-8`, not the `application/json` that I am expecting.

The page itself has examples that I don't know how to access.

How do I get from here to viewing actual JSON?

Comment: Please make your titles describe your problem, not you. That means another person searching later for a solution to the same problem will be able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an endpoint in your URL. (I agree, the documentation is not clear. I had to guess that `/v3` was required.)

So this works for example:

```
import requests
r=requests.get("https://forgeapi.puppet.com/v3/modules") # Add /v3/modules here
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.content) # JSON data is in here
```

The other endpoints are all documented in the link you provided.